# get info from 2 tables at once?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get info from 2 tables in one query, I searched for it on google and it came up with joins?
I got this code

```
mysql_query("SELECT code, url FROM apilinks, links WHERE apilinks.code='$code' and links.code='$code'");
```

but it doesn't seem to work, it outpus this mysql error

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/codyl/public_html/projects/tests/tirl/code.php on line 18
```

I need to have it find url and code, in both the links table and the apilinks table, because the url has a get variable, and 'apilinks' is setup differently than 'links'
so it will have the same looking url but it has to check both tables

Comment: That error seems to be unrelated to the query itself...

Comment: You get a better error message with `mysql_error()`!

Comment: The query is fine. You need to post your code.

Comment: `mysql_query("QUERY HERE") or die(mysql_error())` is great for debugging

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your error is from your SQL query, but anyway:

Your SQL query generates a cartesian product. Every row in apilinks is joined with every row in links. This is rarely what you want. You need to add a `JOIN` condition to the WHERE clause.

From your query, I guess `code` is the column you want to join on.

```
SELECT links.code, url 
FROM apilinks, links 
WHERE apilinks.code=links.code
AND links.code='$code'
```

Or with using an explicit join, which may be more obvious to you:

```
SELECT links.code, url 
FROM apilinks INNER JOIN links ON apilinks.code=links.code
WHERE links.code='$code'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify which `code` column you want:

```
SELECT links.code, links.url 
FROM   apilinks, links 
WHERE  apilinks.code='$code' 
AND    links.code='$code'
```

Comment: I need it to check for code and url in both links and apilinks

Comment: You are already checking for both. If you want to select both, you can do it with `select links.code, apilinks.code`

Answer (score 0):

Another syntax:

```
mysql_query("SELECT a.code, l.url FROM apilinks a, links l WHERE a.code='$code' and l.code='$code'");
```

Note that I am assuming the url field is in the links table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.code, a.url 
FROM apilinks a, links l 
ON ( a.code = l.code )
WHERE a.code = "$code";
```